# How to show wordpress blog post on php sites

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, custom-wordpress-pages

I have a site xyz.com designed using core php.
Also I have 1 wordpress blog xyz.com/blog.
Now I want to show 4 blog post excerpts on xyz.com/index.php from wordpress blog.

I tried connecting wordpress database (`<?php include('blog/wp-config.php'); ?>`) and tried to call data from table.

Comment: You can use Wordpress REST API - https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/ .

Comment: Don't mess up with wp-config.php file because it's main wordpress security file.you can achieve your blog using API.